# What do se and en mean in s'en falloir?

Tags: sens, étymologie

I'm asking HOW s'en falloir means "manquer", [not whether it does](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/32605).

1. What does "se" mean here? Is it a reflexive or reciprocal pronoun here?
2. What does "en" refer to here? De quoi ?

[peu s'en faut | WordReference Forums](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/peu-sen-faut.646113/)

> "s'en falloir" veut dire manquer, mais il ne se construit pas de la même manière.
> Peu s'en faut signifie "il en manque peu (pour que)", cela peut être équivalent à "presque".
> Peu s'en faut est une forme figée pour "il s'en faut de peu".

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe "il", "se" or "en" refer to anything specific in the expression "il s'en faut". It's the way that expression is built.

For example imagine Jean wants to buy a 5 Euro bread but has only 3 Euros:

- **Il s'en faut** de deux Euros que Jean puisse acheter le pain.
- **Il faut** deux Euros de plus à Jean pour qu'il puisse acheter le pain.

The two sentences can be equivalent.

Comment: From this answer, one might make a wild guess that *en* stands for *de plus*. But *s'en falloir* has been used for centuries, and figuring out its exact origin may be impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the answer that the first link in your question leads to, I don't believe that *s'en falloir de* per se is an idiomatic expression, because it has not been declared as such in any dictionary I checked.

Let's look at the following examples of the [Dictionnaire de l'Académie française](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/falloir?page=1) to understand better.

1. **Il s'en faut de cent francs.**
2. **Peu s'en faut/ Peu s'en fallut qu'il ne fût expulsé.**

(1.)
The meaning of example (1.) corresponds to the following explanation in the *Dictionnaire de l'Académie française*: "se dit pour indiquer une différence en moins".
So, instead of the (maybe more common) meaning of needing something ("Il faut de l'argent"), *[s'en]falloir* is used to express the lack of something. The only difference between the two meanings is the perspective, but as @Jonathan has said before, it might not be significant.

As *il faut* is a unipersonal verb, I would consider *se* to be a reflexive pronoun.

*En* refers to *cent francs*. According to Grevisse's Le Bon Usage (Grevisse & Goosse 2008: 869), *en* can be seen as a *complément de verbe* which replaces the *object indirect* "de cent francs".
More precisely, the latter is the "sujet réel" of the unipersonal verb *falloir* (cf. Grevisse & Goosse 2008: ibid.).

(2.)
The second example is, in fact, a fixed expression because of its ancient, non-modifiable structure, which becomes evident when looking at the omission of the impersonal pronoun ("il") and its substitution for the *sujet réel* which is an indefinite pronoun ("peu") (Grevisse & Goosse 2008: 395).

## Edit:

In response to the comment of @jlliagre, I tried to render my thoughts regarding the issue of whether or not *il faut* (and consequently *s'en falloir*) is an idiomatic expression more precisely.
I think what is described in the comment is "just" a syntactic expletive which exists in so-called pro-drop languages. It occurs not only in French but also in other languages, for example [Spanish](https://books.google.de/books?id=TU7_DAAAQBAJ&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=expletivum%20in%20spanisch%20llueve&source=bl&ots=uwfuMiZ4k-&sig=ACfU3U38ADzqBa2LNT9N_HnlEiyKKqTC2g&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjL8Y7DhZ3qAhXF0aQKHUL4CS8Q6AEwBHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=expletivum%20in%20spanisch%20llueve&f=false) (Llueve.), English (It rains.) and [German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletivum) (Es regnet. Note: I recommend the examples in the german version of this Wikipedia Website but it exists as well in French and English).
In addition, as I understand [Gregor Perko](https://revije.ff.uni-lj.si/linguistica/article/view/3799), the degree of *figement* is (arguably) not high enough in the case of "il faut".
In [Dictionnaire des Gallicismes](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=Zik1AQAAMAAJ&hl=de&pg=GBS.PA340), there are only chosen expressions with *falloir*, for example "comme il faut". The same applies to *pleuvoir* and *neiger*. Recent dictionaries and grammars (Larousse, Le Robert, Le Bon Usage and Littré) proceed in the same manner.

*Grevisse, Maurice & Goosse, André ([14]2008): Le Bon Usage. Grammaire Française. Bruxelles: Éditions de Boeck Université.*

Comment: Can you better explain why you believe *s'en falloir de* is not an idiomatic expression?

Comment: The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/idiom) comes up with the following definition (whereas idiom can be seen as a synonym for idiomatic expression): "a group of words in a fixed order that have a particular meaning that is different from the meanings of each word on its own". This is not the case in the given example, because, as I developed in my answer, _se_ and _en_ have their own meanings which they contribute in that same sense to the entirety.

Comment: *S'en falloir* can only be used with an impersonal *il*. The simple presence of this impersonal *il* that has a different meaning than the regular *il* makes any expression using *s'en falloir* an idiom known as *gallicisme* because it doesn't use a metaphor. See https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiotisme

Comment: @jlliagre I have edited my answer to refer to your comment

Comment: *Il s'en est fallu de peu que...* is listed as a gallicism in "Le musée des galliscismes* by Ernest Rogivue.

Comment: Yes, because the degree of _figement_ is higher there. If many people use this exact expression (including "peu") it is likely to be seen as a gallicism. But this is not the same as "Il s'en faut de 100 Francs/ Il s'en faut que tous les citoyens européens soient satisfaits de leur couverture sociale." (last example from Reverso Context) which are not fixed. My point was that _s'en falloir_ **per se** is not an idiomatic expression, because its component parts explain its sense. However, in some fixed expressions, it can be.

Comment: Another example following my reasoning: "Il pleut des cordes" is considered to be an idiomatic expression because a completely new (metaphorical) sense is constructed. But "il pleut" alone is not.

Comment: Well, if it is not an idiom, *il s'en faut de peu* ;-) You have a quite restrictive definition of idiom. Imagine we discover that some tribe in Australia also say *It rains ropes* in its own language, does *il pleut des cordes* cease to be an idiom? Note that Albanian is close: *po bie litarë-litarë*.

Comment: Interesting question! I would say no, because it can't be concluded by the semantics of each word on its own and well...two languages is a little too extreme - even for me ;) You are absolutely right, I have a restrictive definition, accrued from the definition taken literally. Maybe this is a bit idealistic, spoken as a non-native speaker that just loves when languages are self-explanatory in some way and wanted to pass this thought on.

Comment: "As *il faut* is a unipersonal verb, I would consider *se* to be a reflexive pronoun." 1. Thus what does *se* mean exactly here? To himself/herself? 2. "Il s'en faut de cent francs." = He is missing, to himself, more of "cent francs"?

Comment: Can you please edit your answer, rather than reply in comments? Comments can get deleted.